# Compare two data set(two result set) from different data base in java

Tags: java, hashmap, resultset

I am trying to compare two data set from different DB through Java.
Source db:-oracle,sql,other database.
Target `db:Hive`

I have made a JDBC connection to both databases and fetched the result in two different result sets.

```
sourceData  
targetData
```

Now I want to compare the two result sets and point out the differences. The approach I am thinking is to add both result sets to hash map and compare. Please let me know if my approach is correct or is there a better way to do the same.

Please share links that could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its hard to suggest a solution without the comparison logic.
Please mention how you want compare the data. Based on id or name or all the fields.

Comment: @RaMPrabU i want to compare result column wise, table has pk column and non pk columns. i want to compare it column wise. Thanks

Comment: You have to implement equals method and hascode methods properly(as per your logic )and I hope my answer helps in finding the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will help you with hashmap approach itself.
**Assuming** that you set contains unique values.
My following code will help you.

```
Set<Data> soruceData;
Set<Data> targetData;
HashMap<Data,Integer> comparisonMap;
for(Data data:targetData){
 comparisonMap.put(data,0);
}
for(Data data:soruceData){
if(targetData.contains(data))
 comparisonMap.put(data,1);
else
 comparisonMap.put(data,0);
}
```

Now you got a hashmap which say the difference between two list.
1- means present in two sets
0- mean not present in any one of sets

**NOTE** please implement hascode and equals properly while using set and hascode

Comment: Why not use a `Boolean` instead of `Integer`?

Comment: @Lino that also okay

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution to the one proposed by [@Hades](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55586941/5515060), but instead use `Set`s.

Create a holder class, which holds all the values you wish to compare and which overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()`:

```
class Data {
    // the fields you wish to compare

    // override hashCode

    // override equals
}
```

Create `Set<Data> source, target;` (use a `LinkedHashSet` if order of rows is important) and add the rows from the `ResultSet sourceData` to `source` and the same for `targetData`.

Then you can use simple `Set` operations.

1. This will leave all elements in `copy` that **don't** occur in `target`:

   ```
   Set<Data> copy = new LinkedHashSet<>(source);
   copy.removeAll(target);
   ```
2. This will keep all elements in `copy` that **do** occur in `target`:

   ```
   Set<Data> copy = new LinkedHashSet<>(source);
   copy.retainAll(target);
   ```
3. This will create an union of all elements in `copy` and `target`:

   ```
   Set<Data> copy = new LinkedHashSet<>(source);
   copy.addAll(target);
   ```

I've created a `copy` because these operations mutate the `Set`, this way (using a copy) your `Set<Data> source` will be unchanged.

You can also wrap all those calls `removeAll()`, `retainAll()` and `addAll()` in an `if`-statement, which allows you directly to do certain actions. E.g with `removeAll()`:

```
if(copy.removeAll(target)) {
    // elements were removed from copy which were in target
} else {
    // nothing was removed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementation actually depends on your requirements.

Does the rows or columns order matter? Do you have to compare datatypes? etc.

The simplest approach for you would be to run two queries with an `ORDER BY` clause, same for both queries. And compare rows from the data sets in one iteration, something like:

```
ResultSet rs1 = ...;
ResultSet rs2 = ...;

boolean rs1next;
boolean rs2next;
while ((rs1next = rs1.next()) || (rs2next = rs2.next())) {
     //do your stuff here
}
```